# How do you know what a care package contains in Modern Warfare 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

According to the [Call of Duty wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Care_Package):

> If a UAV or Counter-UAV  is dropped,
>   leave it for a teammate as this will
>   award the "Share Package" XP bonus
>   while having the exact same effect, as
>   UAVs and Counter-UAVs apply to the
>   whole team.

How do you know what the air-drop contains without taking it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on what Arda Xi said once the package lands it should show an arrow with an image inside. Here are most of the images that could show up in a care package:

It isn't included in the list below but another possible drop is an ammo resupply crate.

1. [image] when this shows up
   the care package contains has a UAV
2. [image] when this one shows
   up it is a counter UAV
3. [image] this means the package
   contains a sentry gun
4. [image]
   this is a predator missile in a box
5. [image] this is a precision
   air strike
6. [image] harrier
   strike anyone? (I'm not sure this is
   the right picture...)
7. [image]
   attack helicopter is contained
   within
8. [image] a pavelow
9. [image] stealth bomber...
10. [image] Chopper gunner
    (Better pick this one up)
11. [image] Ac-130 controls in this
    box
12. [image] EMP strike
    waiting in the box

Those are all the possibilities for a care package.
All of this information and all of these pictures were gotten from the [Call of Duty Wikia](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Care_Package)

Comment: Nice! I didn't notice the icon of the care package. I'm too excited when I get one and I try to get it quickly :-)

Comment: This is totally helpful. I rarely get a chance to grab a care package, but I'll be on the lookout now.